# using python tool on multiple files

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

there is a tool I write using python that analyze a pdf file by passing it in the cmd

```
c:\python "my_tool.py" -s "my_pdf.pdf"
```

I want to test the tool on 1000 files. how could I run the tool on all of the 1000 files.

I used this

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b C:\Users\Test\Desktop\CVE_2010-2883_PDF_25files') do echo %%f
```

but how can I specify (the tool) and (-s) argument

Comment: Windows batch scripting isn't so nice, you might as well write a python program to do the job.

Comment: could you help me with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `grep` to pass all `.pdf` file to script !

```
c:\python grep *.pdf|"my_tool.py" -s
```

or with this script :

```
for i in $(\ls -d *.pdf)
do
    python "my_tool.py" -s $i
done
```

Comment: the tool I wrote in windows. is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir /a-d/b C:\Users\Test\Desktop\CVE_2010-2883_PDF_25files\*.pdf') do (
  "c:\python\my_tool.py" -s "%%~dnxf")
```

Comment: what if I want to scan all file in this directory? is it correct to do this: ('dir /a-d/b C:\Users\Test\Desktop\CVE_2010-2883_PDF_25files\\*.) ... python it is not a directory it is an identifier

Comment: Use `*.*` in the place of `*.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Unix `find` command you can use

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec c:\python "my_tool.py" -s {} \;
```

This runs your command on each of the pdf files in the current directory

Comment: I'm working on windows, do you know how to do this on windows ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life a lot easier, by making sure the tool can just search a directory for all pdf files:

```
import glob
import os

def get_files(directory):
    for i in glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory, '*.pdf')):
       do_something(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', help='enter filename')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', help='enter directory of pdf files')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.directory:
        get_files(args.directory)
    if args.file:
        do_something(args.file)
```